# How to remove last row of CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, file, csv

I have some code to display CSV file data in PHP. Out of these code is something like this

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

BLANK(this is not any data)

```
<?php
$csvFile = 'abc.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
foreach($csv_data as $data)
{   
    echo "column 2 = ".$data[1];  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

**expected output :**

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

i have only these four rows but it prints 5 with last blank rows. Please suggest me the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: if(!empty(xxx)) echo "xyz";

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:-

```
<?php
$csvFile = 'abc.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
$csv_data  =  array_pop($csv_data); // delete last element of Array
foreach($csv_data as $data)
{   
    echo "column 2 = ".$data[1];  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are appending `<br/>` at the end so it will print blank line at the last as well try this code

```
$count = 0;
foreach($csv_data as $data)
{   
    if($count>0) 
    { 
           echo "<br>";
    }   
    echo "column 2 = ".$data[1];
    $count+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution by adding this code

```
 if (empty($data)) { 
      break; 
 }
```

This is the whole code of my script

```
<?php
$csvFile = 'abc.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
foreach($csv_data as $data)
{   
 if (empty($data)) { 
          break; 
}     
echo "column 2 = ".$data[1];  echo "<br>";
}
    ?>
```